# React/Jest - How to simulate touch "swipe" event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, swiper.js

I have a component that triggers a function call whenever a swipe interaction was done. This swipe interaction can either be executed by touchEvent or mouseEvent. My goal was to check if the function was called, whenever a swipe occured. **But I fail to simulate the touchEvent in a jest test**. Using swiper, react, react-testing-library and jest.

### Online Editor link for testing: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-testing-react-forked-mzze5j)

### The actual class

```
const App = ({ funcCalledOnSlideChange }) => {
  return (
    <Swiper
      pagination={{
        clickable: true
      }}
      modules={[Pagination]}
      watchOverflow
      onSlideChange={funcCalledOnSlideChange}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>
        <img className="slide" />
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>
        <img className="slide-second" />
      </SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
  );
};
```

### And the actual test

```
const mockFunc = jest.fn();

function sendTouchEvent({ x, y, element, eventType }) {
  const touchObj = new Touch({
    identifier: Date.now(),
    target: element,
    clientX: x,
    clientY: y,
    radiusX: 2.5,
    radiusY: 2.5,
    rotationAngle: 10,
    force: 0.5
  });

  const touchEvent = new TouchEvent(eventType, {
    cancelable: true,
    bubbles: true,
    touches: [touchObj],
    targetTouches: [],
    changedTouches: [touchObj]
  });

  element.dispatchEvent(touchEvent);
}

test("should swipe by touch event", async () => {
  const { container } = render(<App funcCalledOnSlideChange={mockFunc} />);
  const swiperSlide = container.querySelector(".swiper-slide");

  act(() => {
    sendTouchEvent({
      x: 350,
      y: 100,
      element: swiperSlide,
      eventType: "touchstart"
    });
    sendTouchEvent({
      x: 200,
      y: 100,
      element: swiperSlide,
      eventType: "touchmove"
    });
    sendTouchEvent({
      x: 150,
      y: 100,
      element: swiperSlide,
      eventType: "touchend"
    });
  });

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(mockFunc).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Actual error:

```
Failed to construct 'Touch': Failed to read the 'target' property from 'TouchInit': Failed to read the 'target' property from 'TouchInit': Required member is undefined.
```

Comment: Have you tried `pointer` from the user-event library? https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/pointer

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, i just gave it up :D

Answer (score 0):

Mock touch event is not quite easy, finally I found the solution and use it on my [slider](https://sliderm.com) libray.

The first step is to create a mocked TouchEvent object containing the Touch object.

**Touch**

```js
export default class Touch {
  constructor(pageX) {
    this.pageX = pageX;
  }
}
```

We don't need the complete properties for this object, we just need the `pageX` property for simulating to swipe left or right.

**TouchEvent**

```js
export default class TouchEvent {
  constructor(type, options) {
    this.type = type;
    this.changedTouches = options.changedTouches;
  }

  preventDefault() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then, we can use a factory to produce the TouchEvent.

```js
import TouchEvent from './touch-event';
import Touch from './touch';

/**
 * Create a mocked TouchEvent object.
 *
 * @param {String} type
 * @param {String} direction
 * @param {Number} distance
 * @return {Object}
 */
export default function touchEventFactory(type, direction, distance) {
  const options = {};
  const touches = [];
  let touch = null;

  if (type === 'touchstart' || type === 'touchmove') {
    touch = new Touch(300);
  } else if (type === 'touchend') {
    if (direction === 'right') {
      touch = new Touch(300 - distance);
    } else {
      touch = new Touch(300 + distance);
    }
  }

  touches.push(touch);
  options.changedTouches = touches;
  return new TouchEvent(type, options);
}
```

Use it in tests:

```
sliderEvent.mock('touchstart', touchEventFactory('touchstart', 'left', 0));
```

The sliderEvent is an EventAdapter in my project, collecting references and also can be used in tests.

You can check out the `tests/features/touch.test.js` in the repo:
https://github.com/terrylinooo/sliderm.js

Hope this helps.